# @ApplicationScoped - is it possible to get temporary injections?

Tags: jakarta-ee, scope, javabeans

I want to set up an @ApplicationScoped caching mechanism that's basically just storing some database values which it reads at startup. Is it possible to do this without holding an EntityManager and other injected dependencies (ie a query factory) all the time? I only need them during initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if the container is really keeping the connection open. But lets say it will. First off you need to have the `EntityManager` injectable through CDI. You can do this like so:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class EntityManagerProducer {
    @Produces
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "my-pu-name")
    private EntityManager em;
}
```

Then within your initialization method you can use:

```
public void init() {
  EntityManager entityManager = CDI.current().select(EntityManager.class).get();
  // Do some stuff here
  CDI.current().select(Entitymanager.class).destroy(entityManager);
}
```

The `.destroy` should ensure that dependency is **not** active anymore.